# Excel - counting values that match across multiple rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am working on a problem where I want to determine the email links between different colleagues. More accurately, I want to see which colleagues email which other colleagues most often, or are CC'd in, etc.

So, if Jane sends an email to an outside company, and CC's colleague John, that would be 1 email communication between them.

I have exported a set of emails into excel where column A contains the "from" data, column B contains the "to" data, and column C contains the C data.

On a different worksheet, I have all the colleague names in a column, and the same names in a row. I want to Countifs or something to sum how many emails contain both Colleague A and Colleague B in any of the From, To, or CC fields.

Make sense? Hoping for some help!

Comment: A representative example of your data, along with your expected output, would clarify your problem and probably engender some responses. To make the data useful edit your question to post it as text, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)

Answer (score 0):

The number of occurrences of A2 in the from field:

```
=COUNTIF(sheet1!$A$1:$A$100000,"*"&$A2&"*")
```

The number of occurrences of A2 in any of the fields:

```
=COUNTIF(sheet1!$A$1:$A$100000,"*"&$A2&"*") + COUNTIF(sheet1!$B$1:$B$100000,"*"&$A2&"*") + COUNTIF(sheet1!$C$1:$C$100000,"*"&$A2&"*")
```

The number of occurrences of B1 and A2 in the from field:

```
=COUNTIFS(sheet1!$A$1:$A$100000,"*"&$A1&"*",sheet1!$A$1:$A$100000,"*"&B$1&"*")
```

In order to count B1 and A2 in all of the fields you have to concatenate the three fields together. In sheet1 column D add

```
=A2 & "; " & B2 & "; " & C2
```

Then count

```
=COUNTIFS(sheet1!$D$1:$D$100000,"*"&$A1&"*",sheet1!$D$1:$D$100000,"*"&B$1&"*")
```

Lastly you'd need to (of course) make sure the names are unique or at least in matching format e.g. the raw email address "john@company.com".